# Modifying a character array, the modified part shows up backwards

Tags: string, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, masm

I have just started learning assembly, and I am trying to modify a character array.

This is my assembly code:

```
.data
data byte 'Five', 0
.code 
    Asm proc
        lea rax, data
        mov dword ptr[rax], 'Four'
        ret
    Asm endp
end
```

And my C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
// external function
extern "C" char* Asm();
// main function
int main()
{
    printf(Asm());
    _getch();
}
```

When I comment out `mov dword ptr[rax], 'Four'`, the result is that the console prints: *"Five"*. But, with the above code uncommented, the result is *"ruoF"*, instead of what I expected it to be, which is obviously *"Four"*.

Why is this happening? How can I get the text to output in the correct direction without having to do some cheap workaround like this: `mov dword ptr[rax], 'ruoF'`?

Comment: You could probably use macros to reverse strings.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Could you post an example of how that would be done?

Comment: You didn't want a cheap workaround, did you? :)

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Well, better than nothing...

Comment: Easy answer: use a proper big endian CPU !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
mov   ebx,'Four'
bswap ebx
mov   [rax],ebx
```

Or, on Intel Atom processors that support `movbe` (can be confirmed with `cpuid`):

```
mov   ebx,'Four'
movbe [rax],ebx
```

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi You're right on `movbe`, answer edited accordingly. `bswap` is available since 486.