# x64 MASM array modification

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, masm

So when I was looking up answers for my issue I came across this post:
[Modifying a character array, the modified part shows up backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593122/x64-masm-modifying-a-character-array-the-modified-part-shows-up-backwards)

Let's say I have an array:

```
.data
array .quad 0,0,0,0
```

To modify the data within the array I would need to use this code:

```
lea rbx, array
mov QWORD PTR[rbx], 1
mov QWORD PTR[rbx-8], 2
mov QWORD PTR[rbx-16], 3
mov QWORD PTR[rbx-24], 4
```

If this is right would it yield `1, 2, 3, 4`?

Comment: No, you need to use positive offsets. The problem in the linked question was byte order (endianness) within a dword.

Comment: ah ok but the logic of getting the effective address and using that as the base pointer to access data in the array and they just modifying that pointer is what I should do?

Comment: That works, yes, but for compile-time addresses you can just write stuff such as `mov qword ptr [array+8], 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endianness, the order of bytes in multi-byte data types, is a difficult concept for beginners in assembly language to understand.

When you move a multi-byte data type (**word**, **doubleword**, **quadword**) into a memory address, the processor stores that address in the reverse order of the bytes provided. Such that in the storing of data:

```
mov     qword ptr [rbx], 1      ;provided      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01h
                                ;stored as     01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00h
```

And for the retrieving of data:

```
mov     rax, qword ptr [rbx]    ;provided      01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00h
                                ;retrieved as  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01h
```

---

However, when each individual **byte** is manually saved, the result corresponds to the code's appearance.

```
mov     byte ptr [rbx], 1
mov     byte ptr [rbx+1], 2
mov     byte ptr [rbx+2], 3
mov     byte ptr [rbx+3], 4

                                ;stored as     01 02 03 04h
```

---

For the sake of answering your question, the usage of **quadwords** would be:

```
mov     qword ptr [rbx], 1
mov     qword ptr [rbx+8], 2
mov     qword ptr [rbx+16], 3
mov     qword ptr [rbx+24], 4

                                ;stored as     01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00h
                                               02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00h
                                               03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00h
                                               04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00h
```

*Note that I used the addition operator instead of subtraction as supplied in your example above.*

Hope this helps.